# how to remove the pop window,which appears when ever trying to open a package in ssis

Tags: ssis, ssis-2005, ssis-2008

An ssis 2005 package has been upgraded into 2008.But everytime i open this 2008 package 
a popup window opens( "welcome to ssis package upgradation wizard").Any sugestion how to disable it

Comment: Anybody faced this problem?

Comment: Check if you have any package/Project not upgraded. And give a try to delete user base files.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes ssis package break.
in this case I prefere to recreate the ssis from new, and copy/past all task to the new